# Using "ü" in an Apple Push Notification

Tags: php, ios

Maybe I am only tired but I can not make following work:

(Extract from my PHP code)

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'censored');

    $socketClient = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Neuer Vertretungsplan heute verf\u00FCgbar.', 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => 1);
    $payload['id'] = 'VPheute';

    $payload = json_encode($payload,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $deviceToken = 'censored';

    $message = pack('CnH*', 0, 32, $deviceToken);
    $message = $message.pack('n',strlen($payload));
    $message = $message.$payload;

    fwrite($socketClient, $message);
    fclose($socketClient);
```

The "ü" is not working of course so I tried to use:

```
"alert" => "Neuer Vertretungsplan heute verf\u00FCgbar."
```

But this is not working either. It always returns the raw string in the notification. Can somebody help me please? Dr. Google was not very helpful...

Comment: try `json_encode($something,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)`

Comment: nope, does not work either

Comment: you then would like to be very specific and explain 'does not work', and show the entirety of the *so called* failing code.

Comment: the problem is, that the notification I get (on my iPhone) is still "Neuer Vertretungsplan heute verf\u00FCgbar." and not "Neuer Vertretungsplan heute verfügbar." So unicodes are not converted.

Comment: actually, in objective-c, `NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: And how does this helps me with php?

Comment: your problem is in your app, not php

Comment: But I can not manipulate how Apple displays my notification message if the app is closed. And besides that in online tutorials for example emojis (packed in unicodes) are working too (Java Script)...

Comment: Are you trying to use the Unicode escape syntax in your alert message there? If so, don't forget you'll need to use "double quotes" instead of 'single quotes' around the string in PHP. Or you will literally end up with verf\u00FCgbar, which is what you're seeing... (What was your original code? I'm surprised a simple ü wouldn't have just worked.)

Comment: I tried that already and I am still getting this "verf\u00FCgbar"...; If I use the simple ü, the notification does not arrives.

Comment: And you're using PHP 7.0 or above, right?

Comment: Correct PHP 7.1 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$unicode = '\u00FC';
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Es ist ein neuer Vertretungsplan f'.json_decode('"'.$unicode.'"').'r heute ist verf'.json_decode('"'.$unicode.'"').'gbar.', 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => 1);
```